# Issues w mysql on xampp

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, port

i've got issues with my port connection on MySQL using xampp. I started MySql but there is not port showing up. And no, I do not have other MySQL running on the same port.

[Xampp controls][image: 1]

Not only changed the port number to 3307 but also uninstalled the other MySQL's on the computer. The result is the same

**Error log**

[MySQL error log file][image: 2]

Comment: what does the logs say?

Comment: MySQL error log file

Comment: What are the specs of the host computer? Seems like memory might be an issue...

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti The database was working nicely two days ago.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though... You could backup your SQL files and apache configs and reinstall xampp